# matlab code turned into unreadable symbols

Tags: matlab

I hit something wrong in Matlab and my code was transformed into unreadable strings of symbols (I . I suspect that this is a simple question for cs people, but I'm just an academic-in-training "end" user of code --that is, I know little theory and forget it easily, unfortunately.

I hit ctr+z but nothing happened, closed it and opened it again, but the symbols are still there. And it doesn't run, the error I get is:

```
The input character is not valid in MATLAB statements or expressions.
```

This is the beginning of my code, in its unfortunate current state:

```
MATLAB 5.0 MAT-file, Platform: PCWIN, Created on: Sun Oct 05 06:57:45 2014   
"‰\*’fTøÄ^L3:!I]ƒÁCƒÒP>æœ³÷>—º0ç²öEEHÉm�0fÈçRHñ)—\¢ßZï³æ3öïû£óû�ã¬½Ö»ÞËó>ïûîZ‡£ñ-IŽjâ»ºø«âÀ§ªú}ÕeßrÏè¼Qƒ3råó$G]µ¾O<ÈÎÉÊÈÍÊLuTø¨Õ4»ÕÁãò²ÇºFå–¯fØ   P«iv«•8\¶\¶\¶œ¶œ¶œ¶Ff�¿â¼XuåÚ­Š½•¥bï•«yÙ¹Cs®��ÕÊ»áßüJ»ËWÓìV+Ù‘a' |5Ínµ²#\¶\¶\¶œ¶œ¶œ¶»†Ére9+F4±šVyU:£ÂæËVÓl$T¸0±÷òe…É¬�9C]W 5kPNîØœ¼Ê«9¹ƒ+{'3ÍVBš­„´Jœ¶:8mupÚêà´ÕÁi«ƒÓV‡r~¨("¾ZAD|µ‚ˆr.±•�f+¡’¶~È°õC†­2lý�aë‡[?äåŒØx)'«8mVÓ*¯–ƒÓn5Í‘3nÐy¡<›—ýòÃùt[ùj†Ü_®°WI«¼·|YüGâ9ËåpT´‚V³s._% 7–¯VÜèPHÍ•72{„+?g°Ê/§íê{Sm÷¦&"_YD†­Ü+÷¦Úí%¹µÄ_IUG¼NVSv”×Éñw­õÐ¡þo‰‡E³Ä§ÐÍfæ&|ÓÈÍ©Y¥•ÞÆÍ°ëÏK‹×¿ô5°GÞÐ·Ã�SØ„”Ýö/`mågf›ºê�;ŸÝÃÄéocÇÜ,µú‡
Ÿíçeƒ;îíáfr9c¯ú^¨ãûðöb§;ÞÙ^À¤ØÅÇ¦°‡÷ç§,Ø<…�¾°müá nöû{ÅÝÛ•zØCþ‡Îo×éÙ@gÃ¿;ãæc:ô[b2yÍÛ­¼L~åz<ìÏ>æ†|^ÜÓÃ=Oélžg¦8¿ØÄú~�­müIÞ°Ÿuæù­÷²FKöþ‰Òžr3if>÷²æÕ&¿™þ“¿‡ºÙŒ›“žªu£Îž•60Ù$)p Áî�†76`ŠÉÆÉ�õ|¬‰?í°ÎÞJ†4ÑÙù~XÖHÜ¸S‡ß�?ÙdÂŠä‚d?ä&ûØ´£µû—°¯™ú
Ñ¯�:¯TUç5/îo ôxÄÇd8ëž1¿ûMè]ÕùOûÙßó…À]Ûô�ø,3Øöñ‡[¤ÞkÂîÛMÄ;ÉÇ—
ÏòÅqñŠØV½­q)ð±Û¤³Lx§õ¢sä1ß½ÎÝjÀn¦ä§XëE‘ãï}ågÌüágâß6?ô3¹\œ„�%>vR˜}C®ñ;é‡œb?»(àÒâ—
```

And so on.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your file isn't code at all, it's a Matlab data file with the wrong extension. You can see this by running

```
>> x = magic(10);        %// creates a 10x10 matrix
>> save('junk.m', 'x');  %// note .m extension rather than .mat
>> edit junk.m
```

You will see something like this in your editor window -

```
MATLAB 5.0 MAT-file, Platform: PCWIN64, Created on: Sun Oct 05 14:21:38 2014
å³B1#V A6å³B1#V å³B1#V // etc etc, lots more junk here
```

which is what a .mat file looks like when you change its extension to .m and open it as code.

So, sadly, I think you have overwritten your code file with some data. If you rename your file to have a .mat extension and then load it in MATLAB, you will be able to see what the data is.

If you have some kind of backup, you may be able to get your code back. Otherwise you're out of luck.

---

P.S. I used to be "just an academic-in-training end-user of code" as well. I spent some time learning a little bit of CS theory and programming languages (on and off over the course of a year) and it has paid back 100x in productivity gains. Not only will you be able to solve many more issues on your own, you'll also be able to do things that you haven't even considered possible to automate your work, leaving more time for the "fun" bit of research. I highly recommend the time investment!

Comment: Thanks!
The explanation was very useful. I discovered that, fortunately, Dropbox keeps several old copies.
A year and on-and-off, really? My recent delving into code has proved beyond useful. However, it feels that progress takes time, and the same research that benefits from computing tools leaves little time for learning said tools -time has to be forced, but I'm doing it. Thanks for the advice and encouragement!

Comment: Well, I was studying for a PhD until about 2010, where frankly I should have learned to code a lot better than I did. I moved into industry in late 2010 and suddenly discovered that I was expected to be a much better programmer than I was! So I estimate that I worked reasonably intensively at improving my programming skills all through 2011 (putting in a couple of hours every evening when I got home from work) and keeping it up at a lower level since then. Reading Stack Overflow and Hacker News helped. So did doing Project Euler problems. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

```
Check the Extension of your file:
```

In MATLAB you can use the command pcode, which preparses your MATLAB code to a form that is unreadable by humans, but runs exactly the same (actually, very slightly faster) as the original MATLAB code. What happens is that for each .m file you pcode, you'll get a new file with a .p extension. The .p file runs the same as the .m file, but is unreadable.

Comment: It is .m , like the rest of my code files, like it was before I hit the mysterious button while half awake :-/